# How do I display a search result message that includes filter criteria?

Tags: 7, views

I have a view to display nodes, with many filters and sorting conditions; that it gets confusing. I want to display the effective filters somewhere, for example *refined by X* or *sorted by Y*. is there any way to print the active filters?

for instance consider I have mobile shop, with a view to list phones.there are lots of fields that user can refine using exposed filters. I want at top of page print a message like:

*showing phones with X Gb ram and Y screen size and Price Z.*

Comment: What do you mean by "effective filters"? Could you maybe make something like [sscce](http://sscce.org/) of it? You know, minimalistic example of what you want, as close to vanilla Drupal as possible? Like, two fields, two filters and show what you got and what you wanted?

Comment: @Mołot Consider I am showing mobile phones in a view, and I have lots of exposed filter for display size, memory, etc. I want to know what filter is effective, and show that, for instance I want to show at top of the page, listing phones with screen size X, and Y GB Memory.

Comment: Please edit your question to provide details. Comments are not for details, they are second-class content that can and will be ignored by many, if not most, users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question. You may have a look at :

- [Exposed Filter Data](https://www.drupal.org/project/exposed_filter_data)

> This module provides a themed function called `get_exposed_filter_output()` which print out the values of the exposed filter used in a view.

- related topic in D.O : [Use data from exposed filter in title or header](https://www.drupal.org/node/658566). It will give you many ideas on how to print out the chosen exposed filters values programatically.